# Facebook MessageDialog callback not working

Tags: android, facebook, messenger

I'm developing the function to send the link + content to user's facebook friends via Facebook Messenger app.

First, I use facebook-android-sdk-4.3

And write following code

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

messageDialog = new MessageDialog(this);
messageDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "send success")
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.e(TAG, "send cancel")
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "send error")
    }
});

if (MessageDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

  ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
          .setContentTitle("....")
          .setContentDescription(message)
          .setContentUrl(....)
          .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(.....))
          .build();

  messageDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

And I overwrite the `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

At last, I run the app, press send, open send message dialog.
And

- I press send message, `onSuccess` called
- I press back key to cancel, `onSuccess` called, too. :((((

How can I catch the callback when user press back key to close the send dialog?

Thanks!

Comment: MessageDialog works with the native app of Messenger only?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same issue that happens with the ShareDialog used for sharing on a feed. When user shares or when he cancels the dialog, I was receiving a callback on onSuccess, and the postId is always null! So I couldn't differentiate between the 2 results.

After some research, I found this [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/890116221030179/). Facebook team replied with the following:

> After some more research, it turns out that this behavior is by design. The SDK reuses the FacebookCallback class for dialogs such as the MessageDialog, but it uses the onSuccess() method to signal any kind of closing of the dialog. This means that onSuccess() will be called when a message was actually sent, but also when the dialog was dismissed without sending a message.

And in my case this was the solution: The user must grant the `publish_actions` permission in a Login process in order to have onSuccess and onCancel both triggered. Also the postId will be returned when the post is successfully posted to Facebook.

I hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Currently, ShareDialog run perfectly on facebook android sdk version 4.3. Only MessageDialog have this bug. :(

Comment: @NamLe yes I tried to give my app permissions, but MessageDialog only triggered onSuccess as a callback. This works only for ShareDialog.